# SSH : "Connection closed by" (debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY)

Tags: ssh, openssl, remote-access

when I try to connect a specific server via ssh I get : Connection closed by 10.5.8.1 (more detail after)

I saw much error similar to mine, but the workaround that seems works with other, don't work here.

The workaround consists to reduce the Cipher options, to reduce the query/response stream between the server and the client. [[1](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2011-February/029392.html), [2](http://www.held.org.il/blog/2011/05/the-myterious-case-of-broken-ssh-client-connection-reset-by-peer/) and much more, but I can't post more than 2 links...]

Here after my ~/.ssh/config

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

Here the result of the ssh connection log

```
ssh -vvv -lmyLogon 10.5.8.1
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/patrick/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/patrick/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug3: cipher ok: aes128-ctr [aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: aes192-ctr [aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: aes256-ctr [aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: arcfour256 [aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: arcfour128 [aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: aes128-cbc [aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: 3des-cbc [aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc]
debug3: ciphers ok: [aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.5.8.1 [10.5.8.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version paramiko_1.10.0
debug1: no match: paramiko_1.10.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.5.8.1" from file "/home/patrick/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<7680<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 169/320
debug2: bits set: 3071/6144
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
Connection closed by 10.5.8.1
```

After a deletion in the `~/.ssh/know_hosts` file via `ssh-keygen -R 10.5.8.1` and a retry, I get a log like this one :

```
ssh -vvv -lmyLogon 10.5.8.1
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/patrick/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/patrick/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug3: cipher ok: aes256-ctr [aes256-ctr]
debug3: ciphers ok: [aes256-ctr]
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug3: mac ok: hmac-md5 [hmac-md5,hmac-sha1]
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug3: mac ok: hmac-sha1 [hmac-md5,hmac-sha1]
debug3: macs ok: [hmac-md5,hmac-sha1]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.5.8.1 [10.5.8.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version paramiko_1.10.0
debug1: no match: paramiko_1.10.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.5.8.1" from file "/home/patrick/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 260/512
debug2: bits set: 3010/6144
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: DSA 5b:d6:fa:56:9a:56:24:db:5a:1d:a3:22:95:6a:26:78
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.5.8.1" from file "/home/patrick/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
The authenticity of host '10.5.8.1 (10.5.8.1)' can't be established.
DSA key fingerprint is 5b:d6:fa:56:9a:56:24:db:5a:1d:a3:22:95:6a:26:78.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.5.8.1' (DSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug2: bits set: 3080/6144
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
Connection closed by 10.5.8.1
```

Obviously I test with the default config, removing the entry for this server in my ~/.ssh/know_hosts file, tryed to find a lib named paramiko for ssh without success, tryed to put only one Cipher at a time... I had no more ideas.

I haven't access to the remote server.
I'am on `Linux pfa-fedora 3.16.6-200.fc20.i686 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 13:48:38 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

[Related to this StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977373/putty-working-not-traditionnal-ssh-command-why)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and found a solution [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/39377/ssh-over-vpn-connection-closed-by-xxxx/).

It was related to the MTU configuration of the interface.

Somehow a smaller value makes it work. (It was 9001)

`sudo ifconfig vpn0 mtu 576`